# Changing validation rules on-the-fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I need a conditional validation in some parts of my app. Right now I am using the following scheme:

```
User.create
User::WithPassword.create
User::WithPhone.create
```

It would be cool if I could change class behaviour on the fly like this:

```
User.with_phone.with_password.create
```

So I tried to do it like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :phone, presence: true, if: :phone_required?

  def self.with_phone
    define_method(:phone_required?) { true }
    self
  end

  private

  def phone_required?
    false
  end
end
```

So it can be used like this where needed:

```
User.with_phone.create(user_params)
```

The problem with this approach is that all instances of User get new behaviour since the actual class changes.

Is there a way to return only the modified copy of `User` class with new instance method `phone_required?` without affecting the "base" class?

**Update**

Thank you for the comments as this was more of an idea, the requirement is that I create users without certain validation automatically, and then when they edit profile, they are dealing with pristine `User` model. I create `with_/without_` on the fly in method missing when needed.

Here's my next iteration:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :phone, presence: true, if: :phone_required?

  def self.with_password
    define_singleton_method(:password_required?) { true }
    self
  end

  def password_required?
    self.class.try :password_required?
  end
end
```

Apparently it's not any better as the singleton method stays there all the time.

Comment: Please don't do this. It flies in the face of proper object-oriented design unless you're trying to employ the "Job Security Through Rampant Obfuscation" pattern. Why not use an `attr_accessor` flag or a first-class column to persist this boolean? This method won't show up ever again, so when you try and re-save an existing record your validation will fail.

Comment: Thank you for the input, in fact I needed custom-built class only for creation time. I am refactoring this from the `User::WithoutPassword` model. I have updated the original question with singleton method creation so it doesn't pollute the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use an instance variable initialized at creation time?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :phone, presence: true, if: :phone_required?

  @phone_required = false

  def self.create_with_phone(params)
    obj = self.create(params)
    obj.phone_required = true
  end

  private

  def phone_required=(v)
    @phone_required = v
  end

  def phone_required?
    @phone_required
  end
end

User.create_with_phone(user_params)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I would like to mimic interface of the base class as clearly as possible without having to add virtual fields. The thing is, at creation time I need `User.without_password.without_phone`, and then just `User.without_password` but once user gets to edit his profile, it's just `User`. I have updated the original post with the new idea.